# Get Array from Dictionary of Values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

**I have a dictionary I need to turn into an array** but can't finish the implementation.

Dictionary of values in `InterfaceController`...

```
var receivedData = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()



func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let tColorValue = userInfo["TeamColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Matchup"] as? String {
        receivedData.append(["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue])

        let eventsList = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)

        for eventM in eventsList {
            NSLog("Event Match: %@", eventM.eventMatch)
        }

    } else {
        print("tColorValue and matchValue are not same as dictionary value")
    }

}
```

Process dictionary of values in `Event` class:

```
    class func eventsListFromValues(values: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) -> Array<Event> {
        var array = Array<Event>()

        for eventValues in values {
            let event = Event(dataDictionary: eventValues)
            array.append(event)
        }

        return array
    }

}
```

Cant figure out this part... Use array to setup the table in `setupTable`:

```
    func doTable() {

            // ...get array of `match`s for use in table set up

            // ...Then set number of Rows
            // ...Then iterate thru the array
                  for var i = 0; i < self.rowTable.numberOfRows; i++ {
                      var row = self.rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(i)
                      // ...setup text label
                   }
    }
```

**EDIT**: For clarification

`doTable` will get any of the `match`s that were received and display them in a table.  So I *think* what I should be doing is getting an array of `match`s and then using them to set the text label in the table.

**EDIT 2**: This is what I have so far

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    class EventSO {
        var teamColor:String!
        var matchup:String!

        init(dataDictionary:[String:String]) {
            teamColor = dataDictionary["teamColor"]
            matchup = dataDictionary["Matchup"]
        }
    }

    var receivedDataSO = [Event]()

    var tColorValueSO = "Red"
    var matchValueSO = "someString"

    var eventSO = EventSO(dataDictionary: ["teamColor": tColorValueSO, "Matchup": matchValueSO])
```

Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: What do you want the `doTable` method to do?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do here, receivedData is an array of dictionaries already? Could you please clarify? Could you tell us about what you want to do in doTable and also what Event is?

Comment: @Adam Hi Adam, I added an EDIT above to try to clarify further, but basically `doTable` will set up my WatchKit table.  So inside of `doTable` I need to get an array of `match`s that I'll be able to iterate through to build the table and set the text of the labels.  I hope that makes more sense!  Let me know if not-

Comment: @Scriptable I added an EDIT above to try to clarify further, but basically doTable will set up my WatchKit table. So inside of doTable I need to get an array of matchs that I'll be able to iterate through to build the table and set the text of the labels.  `Event` is me trying to add a class for the Event items that could possibly be received in the `didReceiveUserInfo` from the iOS side.  Hope that helps clarity a little more, just let me know if not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code makes some assumptions and wont be directly related as I'm not very familiar with WatchKit and the rest of your code.

I don't think that you really need the eventListFromValues method, I done this in a playground in XCode.

```
class Event {
    var teamColor:String!
    var matchup:String!

    init(dataDictionary:[String:String]) {
        teamColor = dataDictionary["teamColor"]
        matchup = dataDictionary["Matchup"]
    }
}

var receivedData = [Event]()

var tColorValue = "Red"
var matchValue = "someString"

var event = Event(dataDictionary: ["teamColor": tColorValue, "Matchup": matchValue])

receivedData.append(event)

func doTable(events: [Event]) {
    myTable.setNumberOfRows(events.count, withRowType: "someRowController")

    for (index, evt) in events {
            let row = myTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as someRowController
            row.interfaceLabel.setText(evt.teamColor)
    }
}
```

So using the above code you should be able to remove the eventListFromValues function, and when you receive userInfo create a new Event object from the values received and add it to the end of the array.

Your doTable function will then just iterate over the array and set the UI parts of the table based on the data on the row.

So to use this code in your specific case you might do something like this:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    var evnts = [Event]()

    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

        if let tColorValue = userInfo["TeamColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Matchup"] as? String {
            var event = Event(dataDictionary: ["teamColor": tColorValue, "Matchup": matchValue])
            events.append(event)
            doTable()
        } else {
            print("tColorValue and matchValue are not same as dictionary value")
        }

    }

    func doTable() {
        myTable.setNumberOfRows(events.count, withRowType: "someRowController")

        for (index, evt) in events {
            let row = myTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as someRowController
            row.interfaceLabel.setText(evt.teamColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is cool, I'm trying to integrate it right now.  On `var event = Event(dataDictionary: ["teamColor": tColorValue, "Matchup": matchValue])` line I get an error "Instance Member tColorValue cannot be used on type InterfaceController".  Any ideas what's going on there to fix? (I put all of the code you listed inside of my `InterfaceController` class, let me know if that was wrong)

Comment: are you trying to do this outside of a function?

Comment: I'm doing all of it inside of the `InterfaceController` class, does that make sense?  I added the code in EDIT 2 so you can see

Comment: yes, You wont be able to put this code: `var event = Event(dataDictionary: ["teamColor": tColorValue, "Matchup": matchValue])` in the class declaration, it would need to be inside a function. In your case, probably in `func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) ` function

Comment: Put `var event = Event(dataDictionary: ["teamColor": tColorValue, "Matchup": matchValue])` and `receivedData.append(event)` inside of `didReceiveUserInfo` then yeah?

Comment: yeah, so your creating the event and dictionary inline

Comment: Then call `doTable(events: [Event])` somewhere in my code like `willActivate` or something then right? (event though I know you said you're not totally familiar with WatchKit, but I need to make sure I call `doTable` somewhere right?)  How would I call that?

Comment: In `didReceiveUserInfo` I don't think I can call `doTable()` with blank parentheses though right?  I'm missing an argument in that case

Comment: Sorry I think doing my code in the Playground might of confused you a little. I've updated my answer above with some more code to advise what your code might look like. So you declare an array on the object (events) which holds all the events received, and each time that an event is received it gets added to the table and the table re-rendered. Now this is the part I'm not too sure on, I do not know if you need to handle re-rendering of the table differently. In theory the above should work. you'll need to add a reference to the table in your storyboard as an IBOutlet too and update the name

Comment: if you have var events: [Event] near the top of your file you do not need `events: [Event]` in your doTable function

Comment: Do you mind editing that code a little bit, I can't tell which parts of the original answer you gave I need to keep or need to remove?  Or are you saying remove all of it?  Or are you saying keep all of it?  Thanks!

Comment: And then I'm still not sure what to put inside of `()` when I call your `doTable()` method in `didReceiveUserInfo`

Comment: Yes sorry i've updated it now. using my code above you need to change, someRowController to your actual controller and need to add a reference to your table, not my myTable example. you just call `doTable()` exactly like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91921/discussion-between-scriptable-and-srmr).